# How to make fieldsets (or any other similar elements) fit their container?

Tags: html, css

so I am working to create this really simple website, but the problem that I keep facing is that when i put to things inside one div, I cant make them fit the container and when I zoom they keep going vertical, for example:

Here is the html:

```
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="Form">
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    <fieldset class="Member">                    
      <legend>Sign In</legend>
      Sign in today for more experience <br><br>

      <b>Email:</b> <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
      <br><br>

      <b>Password:</b> <br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <br><br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes">remember me
      <input type="submit" value="Log&nbsp;in">
    </fieldset>

  </form>
  <fieldset class="Not_member">
    <legend>Not a member ?</legend>
    You can create an account:<br>
    <a href="signup.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="font-size:500%;color: grey;"></i></a>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

and here is my Css:

```
.Form{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:0;
}
.Member {
    width: 40%;
}
.Not_member {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
```

what i want to do is:

1. make each one fit half the container vertically and horizontally
2. make them stay horizontal and shrink with the container, so what i mean that when the window  becomes smaller they become vertical, how can I stop that?

Edit:  I want it like this: https://i.imgur.com/j27PQq4.jpg, and I want it to stop going down like this: https://i.imgur.com/DPwTwkD.jpg

thanks in advance

Comment: Anything with a `float` will not fit it's container. `float` allows the element to "float" above the parent and wrap around content in it.

Comment: it would also help if you posted a picture of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @cfreak so  it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/A4xWYX5.jpg, I want it like this: https://i.imgur.com/j27PQq4.jpg, and I want it to stop going down like this: https://i.imgur.com/DPwTwkD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As long as your "Not a member?" is inside of its own div, you can use:

```
 width: 100%;
```

and/or

```
 height: 100%;
```

Comment: It makes them go ontop of each other, simlar to this: https://i.imgur.com/DPwTwkD.jpg

Comment: Use them alternately. E.g. Just height, just width, inside of div, in the parent div, etc.